# What causes "ASP 0248" error?

Tags: asp-classic

I get this really bizarre error:

> 0x80004005 - Object ObjectContext: 006~ASP 0248~Script isn't transacted. This ASP file must be transacted in order to use the ObjectContext object.

In some cases. I have old ASP pages that call several libraries, one of which does this:

```
IF blnHasError THEN
    ObjectContext.SetAbort
ELSE
    ObjectContext.SetComplete
END IF
```

Which is where the error occurs. But given the obscure error message, I can't figure out what ASP wants or expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calling page must be transacted, meaning that in its header it must declare this:

```
<%@ Transaction=Required %>
```

More documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525667(v=vs.90).aspx).